# How to install libcncurses5-dev for ubuntu 9.10 offline

Tags: kernel

I want to install libncurses5-dev in a PC with no internet connection, while I can download it from another PC having internet.I have tried to install libncurses5-dev by using following commands

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev

The error displayed is

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev

I am trying to download the libncurses5-dev package from internet on other PC but unable to find libncurses5-dev package for Ubuntu 9.10 version. How to download and install the libncurses5-dev package?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 is no longer supported, and is thus off-topic here - however, have a look at [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815) You may be able to download the .deb file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/libncurses5-dev) for offline installation.

Comment: In addition - you should really consider to upgrade to a supported version (if possible). Ubuntu 9.10 was supported until April 2011 - which is .....history ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu launchpad and download libcncurses5-dev.deb then copy it to pendrive, transfer it to the other PC, and give the command:

```
dpkg -i libcncurses5-dev.deb
```

Good luck. And do consider upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

---

Ubuntu 9.10 used libncurses5_5.7, like libncurses5_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_i386.deb

All packages, release version :

```
libncurses5_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
libncurses5-dev_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
libncursesw5_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
ncurses-bin_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_i386.deb
ncurses-base_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_all.deb
ncurses-term_5.7+20090803-2ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Link to all packages http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/

---